# Design Pattern to handle bulk actions in c#

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I wonder is there any design pattern in c#  to handle bulk actions similar to bulk state transition pattern which is in apex? I studied all types of Creational, Structural and Behavioral Patterns but didn't find any pattern in c# similar to that. Thanks for your time.

For reference to know about bulk state transition go to this link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Design_Patterns#Bulk_State_Transition

Comment: The parallel task library comes to mind, but thats all I can think of

Comment: You're trying to find analogue of very special pattern for specific programming platform in general purpose language - C#. I don't think, that makes any sense.

Comment: @Dennis I think you didn't get the question properly. What if we need to handle bulk actions based on change of state in one or more applications, which patterns we need to use in that situation. I just gave an example of a pattern in another language which does the same. I think, now it makes clear I guess. Thanks!

Comment: No, it doesn't. I can't imagine abstract bulk action. I think, there's too much patterns in your head. Patterns are not primary. It's better to solve particular task, and then find any well-known approach or pattern to apply.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask for a pattern in a particular language. Patterns are language agnostic. You implement them in whatever pattern you need to.

Comment: I didn't understand why i got down vote for this. Is this seems an easy question to lot of guys? I don't think so. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Remove the ref to C# and maybe the angry downvoter will change his mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Command pattern (GoF) looks close to this problem. Commands could be your bulk actions. For state transitions (triggers) it looks like the Observer pattern (GoF).

Condition objects are like the subjects in Observer, and you add() observers that are the Commands you want to have executed when the condition becomes true.

You might want to look at Batch Iterator (POSA5) and Command Processor (POSA1). There's a good video for the latter: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PJvnMP94Kqw -- the following link goes right to the meat of Command Processor https://youtu.be/PJvnMP94Kqw?t=707